# How to cancel a setInterval in python?

Tags: python

I am using this code to call a function `doSomething` every 3 seconds. but I want that when `numeroPeticiones== 3`, stop doing it. I have looked for many examples, but none works. In my case, my function continues to be executed eternally, even though the condition of `numeroPeticiones== 3` is fulfilled. how can I solve that?

```
import threading
from threading import Timer
numeroPeticiones=0

def doSomething():
    global numeroPeticiones
    numeroPeticiones=numeroPeticiones+1
    print ("hello, world",numeroPeticiones)
    if numeroPeticiones == 3:
        print("cancel")
        t.cancel()

def set_interval(func, sec): 
    def func_wrapper():
        set_interval(func, sec) 
        func()  
    t = threading.Timer(sec, func_wrapper)
    t.start()
    return t
```

Comment: Because t is in the set_interval function scope and can't be accessed in the doSomething function

Comment: @AGhanima Thanks for answering, I'm new to python, I'm not sure what I should do. my strong is javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  can  do the following, if num is equal to the 3, it wont start the timer

```
from threading import Timer
num = 0

def hello():
    global num
    num += 1
    print("hello, world")
    if (num < 3):
        Timer(3, hello).start()


Timer(3, hello).start()
```

Comment: Timer(3, hello).start() in this line stops the interval... why?

Comment: The  if condition is  what  controls whether the next  timer  starts  or  not